# Is this a valid way to create a web service and is it commonly accepted?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, .net-4.0

I recently inherited a project from a developer that is no longer with us. I'm fairly new to web development and the limited service work I've done involved WCF (.NET 4).

The project includes a series of service calls where an .aspx page is called (often with parameters). The markup of the is something like this...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%
    // <!-- Get tasks -->

    // return as JSON string
    Response.Write(DataAccess.DataManager.DoStuff());

%>
```

All the heavy lifting and processing is done in the DAL. The DAL returns an int or, more often, a JSON string. The .aspx page returns the results to the caller.

This is an internal application so I'm not too concerned about the security of this technique. We are using Windows authorization (ADS). The caller will often, but not for all calls, send a key with the request and that key is checked for authorization.

Is this an acceptable way to create a web service? What is the technique called? I'd like to know more about the guidelines for modifying / creating new services this way as this project will require maintenance for some time.

Comment: I do this with .ashx pages since .aspx pages do a bunch of stuff that is not required for these sorts of things. But this is a good question in general.

Comment: Also, the response type should be json and not html as it will be by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the page needs page specific components it is recommended that you use an [HTTP Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx) for tasks such as this. They will be lighter and faster.

Answer (score 1):

It is *a* way to implement a web service. Looks rather old fashioned to me.

These days one would use WCF for web services - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907578.aspx) and for [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) WCF, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In a sense "anything that works" can count as a web service, since the consumer shouldn't have any reason to care about how the service is implemented, as long as it fulfills the contract.

That said, this looks like a hack devised by someone who was used to using ASPX pages, and didn't have the time or gumption to learn to use frameworks that were designed for this sort of thing. I'd suggest migrating it to WCF, which provides a lot more flexiblity for web services.

Answer (score 0):

(Windows Communication Foundation) WCF is what you want to be looking at just now.

There are basically two formats SOAP and RESTful services.

RESTful are being more and more common and are very easy to consume. They are also easy to develop for in .NET 4.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/06/introducing-wcf-webhttp-services-in-net-4.aspx is a great tutorial with samples that takes you from "File > New..." to having a published RESTful service in .NET 4.